# Unit-тестирование работы с файловой системой

Tags: юнит-тесты, тестирование, test-driven-development

Возможно ли unit-тестирование класса, основная задача которого состоит во взаимодействии с файловой системой? Ну например, мне нужно протестировать класс, который предоставляет возможность записывать/читать биты из файла. Каким образом я могу это сделать? Можно, конечно, записать файл с какими-то тестовыми данными, а в самом тесте проверять что считываются именно те данные. Мне это кажется каким-то костылем. Так ли это и какие есть еще способы протестировать работу такого класса?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте попробуем пройтись по задачке в стиле TDD:

1. Какие публичные методы должен иметь данный класс? Пусть это будет только чтение `Read(path, offset, count)` и запись `Write(name, offset, count)`.
2. Пока мы не пишем их код, пока нам надо придумать, как бы мы их могли  протестировать? Напишем несколько тестов (которые, кстати, помогут нам более точно описать поведение и интерфейс класса):

   1. Прочитать что-то из файла и проверить, что прочиталось именно то что надо.
   2. Что должно произойти, если отдана команда прочитать 100 байт из файла размером 50 байт? Вернуть 50 байт, вернуть ошибку/исключение, или вернуть 100 байт из которых последние 50 - пустые? Выбирайте вариант и пишите на него тест.
   3. Что должно произойти, если файл не существует или недоступен? Опять же, выбирайте "правильное" поведение и пишите на него тест.
   4. Разрешаем ли мы передавать отрицательное значение `offset`, и что оно будет означать (например чтение с конца, а не с начала). Пишем тест.
   5. Будем ли мы поддерживать чтение/запись по локальной сети? Длинные имена файлов (260+)? Запись в системные папки (с требованием админских прав)?
   6. Что еще должно работать и что может пойти не так .. продумайте желаемое поведение и напишите на него тесты.

   Повторите то же для метода записи в файл. Не стремитесь сразу предусмотреть ВСЁ. Учитывайте только то что вам понадобится в обозримом будущем (согласно вашему ТЗ).
3. Теперь можно сделать паузу, и обобщить все те моменты и тонкости которые всплыли при проектировании тестов. Окинуть их взглядом еще раз, прикинуть какие ситуации требуют приватных методов и функций, общих для чтения и записи (например, проверка существования файла, или размера).
4. А вот только теперь можно приступать к написанию кода самого класса чтения/записи в файл!
5. Встретили какое-то еще условие, или граничный случай в процессе разработки - отлично, напишите на него тест, а потом код.
6. В процессе эксплуатации класса выявился баг - тоже отлично, пишите на него тест, и только потом исправляйте баг (и тестом проверяйте, что он исправлен, и что в процессе исправления ничего из другого не сломалось).