# Как писать unit тесты на класс работающий с файловой системой?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, файловая-система

У меня есть класс который работает с директориями и файлами. К примеру в нем есть конструкции которые :

1. проверяют наличие вложенных папок в переданной директории
2. проверяют наличие файла определенного во вложенной директории
3. копируют / читают файл...

Для всего этого я исспользовал стандартные классы C#:
DirectoryInfo, FileInfo, Path, Directory

Я конечно могу написать обертку для этих классов, а затем заменить ее на stab объект и уже после тестировать методы класса, но я не хочу этого делать так как моя обертка будет подобием велосипеда приводимого в движение мотоциклом... Подскажите как бы вы поступили в данной ситуации ? Как вообще писать юнит тесты для подобных объектов ?

Comment: Стандартные классы/методы не тестируют. Предполагается, что они всегда работают правильно. Вопрос в том, какой дополнительный функционал к стандартному приносят ваши классы. Максимум, что можно сделать - создать в тесте вложенные папки и проверить, что вернёт ваш класс.

Comment: ^+, но, имхо, это будут уже не юнит-тесты

Comment: Если ваши классы только и делают, что вызывают `Directory.Exists()`, `File.Exists()` и `File.Copy()`, то что вы тут тестировать собрались?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/799311/unit-тестирование-работы-с-файловой-системой?rq=1

Comment: @KAGGDesign Я тестить не методы стандартных классов собираюсь, а методы собственного. Мой класс запускает сторонний процесс (передаю в интерфейсном типе ссылку на класс запускающий его ), останавливает его, задает параметры запуска, Считывает файл который другой процесс сформировал по его остановки и тому подобное.

Comment: @tym32167 Мой класс не только эти методы вызывает. Он выполняет работу описанную в моем комментарии выше. Дело в том что по мимо выполняемой работы он копирует и читает файлы, а так же проверяет наличие соответствующих директорий.

Comment: не значит ли это, что у вашего класса много обязанностей, и его можно разделить на несколько классов, и уже пробовать тестировать более мелкие классы?

Comment: @tym32167 У меня уже есть ряд классов которые работают с файлами, тем самым сторонним процессом и прочим. Данный класс который я собираюсь протестировать в одном методе вызываемым после остановки процесса просто дожидается формирования файлов и копирует их. А так же к примеру формурует путь к запускаемому процессу ища данные в списке вложенных директорий... Я не знаю как это перенести в другие классы, так как часть этого - формирование параметров для конструкторов других классов.

Comment: К примеру мой класс работающий с процессом получает путь к данному процессу. А я в классе который хочу протестировать формирую его:
new DirectoryInfo("Path").GetDirectories().First("ищу папку по условию").GetFiles("Ищу файл процесса")

И тому подобные конструкции есть

Comment: Ладно, давайте зайдем с другого конца. Вот вы написали ваши классы. Вы их запустили, убедились, что они работают. Эти классы будут меняться в будущем? `просто дожидается формирования файлов и копирует их` - когда нибудь эта логика будет меняться? Если да, то выносите её в отдельный класс и там тестируйте. Если нет - то нет смысла текстировать 3 строчки кода, которые уже вами проверены и никогда не поменяются.

Comment: Этот класс - абстрактный, а метод виртуальный. Т.е. я предполагаю через абстрактную фабрику создавать ряд таких классов, где смогу менять логику взаимодействия со сторонним процессом. По сути он выносит логику взаимодействия с процессом из основного класса для того что бы она могла меняться. 

Данный метод в основном меняться не будет, однако вполне возможно мне понадобится его переписать в одной из реализаций данного абстрактного класса (по этому он виртуальный).

Comment: @tym32167 Хотя впринцепи верно говорите, я могу ряд этих данных перенести в конкретную реализацию и тогда тестировать их не придется. Видимо только рефакторингом решить получится.

Comment: я бы не стал решать задачу наследованием, я бы предпочел композицию. Вот у вас есть класс А, в нем логика, есть класс Б, он принимает класс А как параметр и следует его логике. В итоге класс Б завязан на файловую систему, но он максимально тупой. Класс А ничего не знает ни о каких файлах, его можно тестить вдоль и поперек.

Comment: Если так у вам не решается, то можно зависимости крутануть. Например, у вас есть класс А, который содержит логику, он принимает как параметр интерфейс И, с нужными методами. Класс Б, завязанный на файловую систему, реализует интерфейс И и потому может быть передан как параметр. В итоге, класс А так и не узнает о файлах, он будет знать только об интерфейсе, который можно замокать/стабить/фейкать, класс Б вообще ни о чем, кроме файлов, не в курсе, его текстить не надо.

Comment: @tym32167 Попробую как вариант. Мне больше всего наверное интерфейсный вариант подойдет если по данному пути следовать. Благодарю.